# I have arrays and i want to loop through them and assign them with same value but they are mixed up

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop

I want to get all with the same id_attribute_group and show them but the arrays with the same id_attribute_group are spread apart. I would like tho loop through them multiple times.

```
array(8) {
  ["id_attribute"] => string(1)
  "1" ["id_attribute_group"] => string(1)
  "1" ["attribute"] => string(1)
  "S" ["group"] => string(4)
  "Size" ["reference"] => string(6)
  "demo_1" 

}
array(8) {
  ["id_attribute"] => string(2)
  "11" ["id_attribute_group"] => string(1)
  "2" ["attribute"] => string(5)
  "Black" ["group"] => string(5)
  "Color" ["reference"] => string(6)
  "demo_1" 

}
array(8) {
  ["id_attribute"] => string(1)
  "2" ["id_attribute_group"] => string(1)
  "1" ["attribute"] => string(1)
  "M" ["group"] => string(4)
  "Size" ["reference"] => string(6)
  "demo_1" 
}
```

so it should loop once and get all with same number and assign them,loop again and get all with the second one and so on.

Comment: Please show us (a sample of) the expected outcome. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing more about your use case it's hard to tell for certain. However, it seems to me that a simple sorting algorithm (which effectively groups the array by `id_attribute_group`) followed by a loop to output is all you need:

**Code**

```
// Input array
$array = [
    [
        "id_attribute"       => "1",
        "id_attribute_group" => "1",
        "attribute"          => "S",
        "group"              => "Size",
        "reference"          => "demo_1",
    ],
    [
        "id_attribute"       => "11",
        "id_attribute_group" => "2",
        "attribute"          => "Black",
        "group"              => "Color",
        "reference"          => "demo_1",
    ],
    [
        "id_attribute"       => "2",
        "id_attribute_group" => "1",
        "attribute"          => "M",
        "group"              => "Size",
        "reference"          => "demo_1",
    ],
];

// Sort with reference to id_attribute_group
uasort($array, function($a,$b){
    return $a["id_attribute_group"] <=> $b["id_attribute_group"];
});

// Output data    
foreach($array as $item){
    echo "{$item["group"]} {$item["attribute"]}\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
Size S
Size M
Color Black
```

**Notes**

- Here the `uasort` sorts by the value `id_attribute_group` in each sub array.
- Using `uasort` we maintain the original keys so you can always resort etc.

If you want to do something different with each group (e.g. separate them out) then you can update the code to something like:

**Additional Code**

```
uasort($array, function($a,$b){
    return $a["id_attribute_group"] <=> $b["id_attribute_group"];
});

$last = false;
foreach($array as $item){
    if($last && $last != $item["id_attribute_group"]){
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "{$item["group"]} {$item["attribute"]}\n";
    $last = $item["id_attribute_group"];
}
```

**Output**

```
Size S
Size M

Color Black
```

---

### Updated Solution

It's probably easiest to reformat your array first and then loop over the details you need:

```
$transformArray = [];

foreach($array as $item){
    $transformArray[$item["id_attribute_group"]][] = $item;
}

foreach($transformArray[2] as $color){
    echo "{$color["attribute"]} ";
    foreach($transformArray[1] as $size){
        echo "{$size["attribute"]} ";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

// Output: Black S M
```

Comment: I need it to be like one color and all sizes,then again for next color all sizes and so on.